# Changing font of an entire Google Slides presentation

Tags: google-slides, font

Is there a way to change the font of an entire Google Slides presentation all at once? If not, this would be a very nice feature to have, and I suggest that google add it. [Note: I am not asking about how to change the default font, because that does not apply to existing text.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to View -> Master and change the font in the master slide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, by using the Google Sheets API. Maybe the easier way to use it is by using Google Apps Script.

It's possible that there is a Google Slides add-on that does this. If it already exists, you could find it from the Google Slides toolbar by clicking on the Addons menu then on Get addons.

Comment: Thanks for that information, but I was hoping it would be easier than that. If anyone happens to know which addons can do that, that would be nice to know so I don't have to just try them at random. It's not really a priority for me, but I'm having the hardest time deciding whether I prefer Times New Roman (serif) or Arial (sans serif), and it would be nice to be able to switch effortlessly back and forth!

Comment: I think that you should edit your question to add more details. I.E. i didn't mentioned that Google Slides themes / master slides that might be helpful if you are open to change your how do you create presentations (assuming that you usually add text shapes rather than using slides layouts)

Answer (score 0):

Go to slide -> edit theme and then Command + a (or just go one by one) and change the font

This will change add the font to the theme and all the slides.